# why switchsniffer dose not work under win10 bits?

Tags: windows-10, sniffing

i have a `switchsniffer` and it was works normal under windows XP and works in Win32 with administration permissions but now in **windows10 64 bits** it dose not work at all , even i downloaded win pcap for win10 and same problem , Dose anyone know the reason and how i can run the program ? i even have only this version 1.4.0 and can't find newer versions to test it So how can i make this works with me ??

Comment: If the program is a 16-bit application that would be the reason.   Is the application a 16-but application? 64-bit versions of Windows cannot run 16-bit software.  The only way to run 16-bit software on a 64-bit install of Windows 10 is to use a VM with a 32-bit version of Windows

Comment: @Ramhound I played around with it years ago. It is 32-bit but still uses the Windows 2000 driver model and Win32 API. Good luck with that on a 64-bit WIndows 7 or later.

Comment: Windows 2000 driver?  Good luck getting that to work on anything except Windows Vista

Comment: @Ramhound I know. The only reason I played with that software is that we had a couple of developers who used it and it stopped working when they went to WIn7 64-bit. As the resident IT guy I got to troubleshoot. Not actually a driver, but it interacts with the network-card and WinPCap using Win2000 semantics. Win10PCap might just work (I never tried), but only on a 32-bit system.

Comment: Win10Pcap works on 64-bit systems, but you need a Packet Sniffer to go with it. CommView is a better packet sniffer and will likely do what you want. I use CommView.

Comment: @John commview can see other PC in network traffic ? i not think so

Comment: @Ramhound may be a newer version will work in 64bits ? i can't find in net any newer version than 1.4.0 version , Could you help me finding it for me please ?

Comment: @Tonny may a newer version work ?

Comment: @Kimoo - No; The software was discontinued; There isn’t a compatible version.  The **detailed** answer you received explains that in detail

Comment: CommView can see all traffic in a subnet and has additions to see outside of a subnet.

Comment: @John sorry i really very want to find a way to run switchsniffer , cause the forum not allowed to talk about other programs

Comment: @Ramhound i hope to find someway to make swtichsniffer works

Comment: @Tonny it's impossible for me to setup 32bits windows , due that most of programs i use now have 64bits versions only.
so i know that winpcap not work in 64bits now , but i still hope to find away to run it , i really very need to run switchsniffer , i have no other choice , not want any other programs as it dose not do what switchsinffer do

Comment: @Tonny :'( , please someone try to help with an idea or try , may be there is some un- normal fix for it , like replacing files or installing drivers , elc elc

Answer (score 2):

Switchsniffer is ancient and the maker has discontinued the software.
The latest version is 4.2.1 and predates Windows 10. Your version is even older.
In fact, even the latest version says "Windows 2000 and Windows XP". It was never intended to work under newer Windows versions.
You can still find trial-versions of the latest release on various shareware web-sites. It is possible that such a later trail-version can be used with the license you currently have to become a full version.

Even so, it is unlikely that it will ever work on Windows 10.
Besides that most Windows 10 installations are 64-bit, the Windows 10 internal drivers and security model is also quite different and will most likely prevent to software from working.
(Even with a recent Win10PCap version. In fact, the reason Win10PCap exists is purely because the original WinPCap couldn't be made to work in Windows 10 due to those same changes to driver and security model.)

The best chance you have is to setup a 32-bit Windows 10 installation with the 32-bit version of Win10PCap and try it on that. That may work.